# Mожно ли перенести данные из нескольких полей в диалоговом окне в одну колонку в QTableWidget главного окна

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Имеется главное окно,в котором отображается таблица QTableWidget. Новая запись вносится из диалогового окна, которое появляется при нажатии кнопки "Добавить запись", данные переносятся в таблицу с помощью QDataWidgetMapper.  В таблице есть колонка ФИО, а в диалоге добавления записи это три разных поля: Фамилия, Имя, Отчество. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы информация их этих 3 полей вносилась в одну колонку ФИО в таблице через пробел?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что как-то так:

```
class Dialog {
//...
signals:
    void userName(QString firstName, QString secondName, QString surname);
private slots:
    void emitUserName() {
        // Берем из lineedit'ов соответствующие значения
        emit userName(ui->firstName->text(), 
                      ui->secondName->text(), 
                      ui->surname->text());
    }
}

class MainWindow ... {
//...

public slots:
    void addUser(QString firstName, QString secondName, QString surname) 
    {
        // Формируем одну строку ФИО из трех
        QString userFullName = QString("%1 %2 %3").arg(firstName)
                                                  .arg(secondName)
                                                  .arg(surname);
        // Добавляем в таблицу соответствующую запись
    }
}
```